# display custom attributes outside the product page (view.phtml)

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm having this problem where i want to display a custom attribute outside the product page in magento. (view.phtml).

For example. I would like to display custom attribute (its value) to specific place in list.phtml (not navigation layout) and in home page. I tried so many solution, but nothing worked.

Any guidance or assistance would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please post some code of what you tried

Comment: please be a little more specific on what you want to achieve.

Comment: for example: I managed to display wanted attributes with the following code:

$_product->getData('shoes_model');

in my product view page. But with this code, i'm not able to call this function when i want to display the attributes on home page of my web site. it returns nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To display a custom product attribute on the product list page

Go Admin -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes

Set "Used in Product Listing" to Yes

Then in 'list.phtml'

Add `$_product->getData('attribute_name_here')`

Comment: thanks, this work perfect on list.phtml but on home page isn't not. any idea?

Comment: What code are your using on your homepage (I need to know the block type and template)?

Comment: i just posted code that I use on my custom theme template.

Comment: I just need the code you added to your homepage cms page . Something like `{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}`

Comment: is it possible that I don't have block code, as it is empty. I build the theme from scratch, and I only use the code I provided. 

is it possible to display attribute value anythere on the web site. outside view page and list page?

Comment: In admin cms page -> homepage try adding ` {{block type="catalog/product_list" limit="8" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
`

Comment: Also what is the name of the field you want to display

Comment: hi. i managed to solve this issue in another way. thanks r.s for all you effort and help.

Comment: @R.S, if set "Used in Product Listing" to Yes, why we need to write `$_product->getData('attribute_name_here')` in list.phtml ?

Comment: "Used in Product Listing" add that attribute to the flat table... but you still need to edit the template to display it

Answer (score 2):

To display a product manufactures attribute on the product list page

Go Admin -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes

Set "Used in Product Listing" to Yes

Then in 'list.phtml'

```
 <?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') ?>
```

Comment: Need to show this at homepage. any solution?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeText() on a non-object

Answer (score 1):

In Magento-1.9, Display the custom attribute settings

**Magento Admin Panel** -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes -> Add Attribute ->

**Frontend Properties** -> Visible on Product View Page on Front-end -> Yes

Once you can try this method.